# Excel group by substring

Tags: excel, grouping

I am extremely new into Machine learning Feature of Python. I wanted to group i.e. create a cluster based on specific texts from rows. In [image: Input Excel] there are 3 columns Sr no, Name and Summary. I wanted to create a cluster based on the specific values from the summary text i.e. if the summary contains the text "***Veg***", then it should be in one cluster and if the text contains "***Non Veg***", then it should be in another cluster. Expected Output [image: Output Excel], where the third column will contain the clustered value. ***All veg are grouped to Cluster 0 and Non Veg to cluster 1***

K-means can solve this for me. But how to cluster based on the text from the summary. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome!!!, You know what is meaning of `cluster`?

Comment: It doesn't look like you need K-means at all!

Comment: @VivekSable:According to best of my knowledge, grouping set of similar objects into one group is called clustering.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga:can you please suggest a better solution.

Comment: You are merely choosing to label something based on a very simple rule, `"veg" in text` or `"Non Veg" in text"`. This doesn't require machine learning.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : Thanks for your help.:)

Comment: Grouping based on `if text contains "veg"` is not clustering. There is no statistics involved there.

Answer (score 1):

I would go one further than suggestions in the comments and say that you don't need to use Python for this task. Why not just include the following formula in the `cluster` column:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("non veg", D3)), 1, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("veg", D3)), 0, -1))`

Assuming the top-left corner of your tale is B2, and this is the formula in the first row (i.e. in cell E3 of the table). This should give 0 for any cells containing `non veg`, 1 for cells containing `veg` and -1 for any rows containing neither.

You can of course do something similar in Python as suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga, but if your input and desired output are in excel, and there's an easy way to do it in excel, I would suggest that's easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlrd` for read Excel file.

You can use `pandas` to read Excel file also.

Following Demo is with `pandas`

Steps

1. Read Excel file and create `Dataframe` from it. `pandas.read_excel` method.
2. Write a function which return cluster number according to `Summary` value in each row.

   `Input to this function is row
   output is 0(Vegetarian), 1(Non Vegetarian), -1(not define)`
3. Apply this function to each row of Dataframe.
4. Write final output back to Excel file by `pandas.to_excel` method.

**code:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = "43583564_input.xlsx"
>>> df = pd.read_excel(a)
>>> df
   sr. no Name              Summary
0       1   T1      I am Vegetarian
1       2   T2  I am Non Vegetarian
2       3   T3  I am Non Vegetarian
3       4   T4      I am Vegetarian
4       5   T5  I am Non Vegetarian
>>> def getCluster(row):
...     if row["Summary"]=="I am Non Vegetarian":
...         return 1
...     elif row["Summary"]=="I am Vegetarian":
...         return 0
...     else:
...         return -1
... 
>>> df["Cluster"] = df.apply(getCluster, axis=1)
>>> df
   sr. no Name              Summary  Cluster
0       1   T1      I am Vegetarian        0
1       2   T2  I am Non Vegetarian        1
2       3   T3  I am Non Vegetarian        1
3       4   T4      I am Vegetarian        0
4       5   T5  I am Non Vegetarian        1
>>> df.to_excel("43583564_output.xlsx")
```

Comment: but have you understand code that is more important.